# WiFi driver for broadcom 802.11

Tags: 22.04, broadcom, macbook

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 on an external hard drive from my MacBook Air.
Interestingly while it was in trial mode I went to Additional Drivers and I was able to select the Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driver and it worked. However after the installation completed and rebooted the driver couldn't be found. Now obviously the MacBook does not have an ethernet port so there's no network connection.